The use of linker files (.ld files) in embedded bare-metal programming
After the .LD file(linker file) of an embedded bare metal specifies that FLASH is not writable,
for example:
MEMORY { 
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
}

how do the bare metal ensure that this access permission(or attribute) is not violated？
Could it be that GCC statically checks the program code to make sure the program doesn't write FLASH? But what about runtime?

All that declaration does is advise the linker on how to lay out the executable.  It has absolutely zero impact at runtime.

@TimRoberts So as an advise, this declaration actually doesn't impose any access restrictions either at compile-time or runtime, right?

Correct.  It certainly can't have any effect at compile time, since the compiler doesn't see it.  It is POSSIBLE for the operating system linker to use the section attributes from the executable to set page attributes, but I don't think you'll find that in an embedded environment.

@TimRoberts Wonderful! the difference between operating systems and embedded environments is also something I've been considering. You've completely resolved my confusion. Thank you!

@TimRoberts Wait a moment, I want to clarify two more questions:
1.The linker itself does not impose any access restrictions either.
2.In a bare-metal embedded environment (without an operating system), when an ELF file is installed on the device, it will not be subject to any access restrictions (for example, in the case I mentioned, the FLASH is still writable), correct?

Right.  If you step back and think about it,  how could it?  Most flash chips have a way to protect pages of flash, if that's important.

@TimRoberts Absolutely correct, this is exactly what I wanted to confirm. Thank you.

You have it backward, the compiler sorts items into known sections (so long as you dont muck with it and you write code that does not stomp on other sections).  The linker then does what you tell it to do with each section.  You are the only one that insures it happens properly the tools do what you tell it.

The flash has nothing to do with this nor these tools.  bare metal or not operating system or not you want no writes to flash then dont write to flash.  while I have seen mcus that it is easy to trash the flash, generally as mentioned above the hardware itself protects writes and to properly write a flash there is some sort of a procedure that you have to follow.

the processor is about as dumb as a thing can be, it does not know instructions from data, you do, you insure that it only tries to decode and execute instructions.  Likewise it is impossible to tell operating system from bare metal, it just sees bits come in. It does not know an address from data, etc    note....an operating system is a bare metal program...protecting flash/ram/peripherals from improper access is a system design problem not a tools/language problem.  Although the compiler will help with well written code.

elf files are not installed on the device, that would require, ideally , an operating system to parse the elf file place the contents in the appropriate places and then branch to it.   many tools can extract the flash image from the elf file and load that into a device.  I assume that is what you meant?

@old_timer Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Suppose I play a trick like this: I set the permissions of FLASH in the linker to 'rx', but I also have the program code attempt to write ('w') to FLASH. I'd like to know if such a trick would succeed?

well the program code can do whatever, it is up to you as a programmer to not write a flash address.  Now to actually change the flash, there is a procedure, simply writing to a 0x0800xxxx address will not change things.  It may or may not hang, probably not.  In order to actually change the flash you have to look at the procedure, it is not difficult.

If/when you do get to the point where you do want to change the flash runtime you have to know if you can, you usually cannot change (erase then write) the flash bank you are executing from.  which is not your question but its another thing to know

the linker (rx) is simply a shortcut and perhaps I demonstrated this or perhaps I skipped it.  you can try the simple example or make your own, only use your MEMORY definition with no SECTION definition.  the (rx) and (rwx) will tell the linker to put .text and .rodata in the FLASH space and the read/write .data and .bss in the RAM space.  But that wont do what you want it to do, you need a > RAM AT >FLASH for the .data.  Actually .bss does not need the AT > FLASH because it is not loadable.

(rx) is not a protection thing it is a linking thing, not sure if you are understanding this.  you are telling the linker to put the bucket by the garage door when you finish washing my car and leave the car in the driveway.  That does not mean the bucket nor the car can get put away in the garage by me later.

I would have run out of room in the answer for all these experiments, this is what you need to be doing on your own to learn the tools.  for example as you have it (rx) goes to FLASH in MEMORY, but what if in SECTIONS you tell .rodata to go to RAM.  Does it error out?  Does it warn? does it just do one of those things and not another and not say anything about it?  Thus why I dont like those (rx) (rwx), there is IMO no use for them if you use SECTIONS, which you need to if you want .data and .bss initialized.

in any case all this stuff is link time, runtime can do whatever the HARDWARE allows.

This
MEMORY { 
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
}

plus "embedded bare-metal programming" has the strong smell of an STM32 microcontroller.  How could I possibly guess that?   Give it time, you will see. (Do not give up).
Even if it is not I am going to use a target that is very friendly to your question.  I think you got the real answer to your question in the comments.  This is just overkill.
Bare-metal programming, as in bare metal mcu programming, as in I am not just in a sandbox with all the peripherals handled in api calls, toolchain, linker, everything already done (the non-bare metal experience).  But the I am talking to the peripherals that I read the documentation to figure out and telling the toolchain what to do including writing my linker script...means...Almost zero of your time is actually writing application code.  All of your time is reading documentation and doing experimental throwaway code.  But you have complete control over everything and your binary is yours not someone else's, you do not have the very scary vendor library code, etc.  Lean and mean.
You have to know what docs and where to get them...and...you have to master the toolchain.  One of the reasons gnu is popular is because it can be beaten into submission.
Here is the answer to your question.
notmain.c
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int );

const unsigned int myconst = 0x11111100; //read only  .rodata
unsigned int mydata = 0x22222200; //read/write, initialized, .data
unsigned int mybss;  //read/write, uninitialized, .bss
extern unsigned int myextern; //defined externally, used as read/write in this code

int notmain ( void )
{
    static unsigned int mystatic = 0x33333300; //read/write pre init local global .data
    unsigned int ra; //local, stack
    myextern = mybss;
    mybss = mydata + 1;
    for(ra=0;ra<1000;ra++) fun(ra);
    return(mystatic);
}

build
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding  -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.o > notmain.c.list

notmain.c.list
notmain.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <notmain>:
   0:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   2:   25fa        movs    r5, #250    ; 0xfa
   4:   2400        movs    r4, #0
   6:   4a09        ldr r2, [pc, #36]   ; (2c <notmain+0x2c>)
   8:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (30 <notmain+0x30>)
   a:   6811        ldr r1, [r2, #0]
   c:   6019        str r1, [r3, #0]
   e:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (34 <notmain+0x34>)
  10:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
  12:   3301        adds    r3, #1
  14:   6013        str r3, [r2, #0]
  16:   00ad        lsls    r5, r5, #2
  18:   0020        movs    r0, r4
  1a:   3401        adds    r4, #1
  1c:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <fun>
  20:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
  22:   d1f9        bne.n   18 <notmain+0x18>
  24:   4804        ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; (38 <notmain+0x38>)
  26:   bc70        pop {r4, r5, r6}
  28:   bc02        pop {r1}
  2a:   4708        bx  r1
    ...
  38:   33333300    teqcc   r3, #0, 6

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <mydata>:
   0:   22222200    eorcs   r2, r2, #0, 4

Disassembly of section .rodata:

00000000 <myconst>:
   0:   11111100    tstne   r1, r0, lsl #2

Disassembly of section .comment:

00000000 <.comment>:
   0:   43434700    movtmi  r4, #14080  ; 0x3700
   4:   3128203a            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x3128203a
   8:   2d393a35    vldmdbcs    r9!, {s6-s58}
   c:   39313032    ldmdbcc r1!, {r1, r4, r5, ip, sp}
  10:   2d34712d    ldfcss  f7, [r4, #-180]!    ; 0xffffff4c
...

The elf file is a container file format that has flexibility that specific binaries for specific targets can fit.  It has ways to specify the stuff we call a binary like the data and instructions but also debug stuff, text, and other items.   The mcu cannot read this, the logic has very specific hardware rules defined by IP vendors (like arm) for purchased IP from the chip vendor (st).  We have rules from the IP vendor's IP and from the chip vendor itself and part of the bare metal job is to get the right bytes in the right places.
Some folks argue the read elf and map tools, some of us use the disassembler and some use all.  GNU binutils is a very powerful array of tools that you can sometimes use against files created by non-gnu tools.  I prefer to mostly use the disassembler (objdump) but then know what I am looking at.  You can clearly see that it is trying to disassemble data as well as just text stuff that is not part of the "binary" (the comment section).  This is fine for targets like arm targets, this approach does not work for x86 very well and other variable length instruction sets.
I marked what I expect the compiler (gcc) will do with the code I wrote and this is the compiler part of your question...
We can directly see that mydata landed in .data
Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <mydata>:
   0:   22222200    eorcs   r2, r2, #0, 4

and my const in .rodata
Disassembly of section .rodata:

00000000 <myconst>:
   0:   11111100    tstne   r1, r0, lsl #2

I want to say but maybe wrong that older gcc versions would make this .text not .rodata.
.bss, .data, .text go back decades but are not part of the C language they are just something in history created to solve this problem and as programmers tend to do, they have carried on to the present.
(.text is your binary, instructions.  .data is read/write pre-initialized, non-zero, and .bss is read/write init to zero).
our .bss stuff is not shown in this object file disassembly we will see them in the final binary.
This
   e:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (34 <notmain+0x34>)
  10:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
  12:   3301        adds    r3, #1

would be this
mybss = mydata + 1;

So 0x34 is going to be filled in by the linker from the address of mydata the compiler cannot know the address space code and data are in different places so it has to generate code that relies on the linker to patch up later. This is one way that our system level design keeps read write as read write and read only as read only and lets us control where everything lives in the address space.  Keeping code from writing to read only is a system level solution, not a tools problem.
So filling this in so you can see if you care what the compiler did in detail.
00000000 <notmain>:
   0:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
   2:   25fa        movs    r5, #250    ; 0xfa
     this is the upper limit of ra this will be 1000 eventually
   4:   2400        movs    r4, #0
     this is ra the local variable in the loop
   6:   4a09        ldr r2, [pc, #36]   ; (2c <notmain+0x2c>)
     get address of mybss
   8:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (30 <notmain+0x30>)
     get address of myextern
   a:   6811        ldr r1, [r2, #0]
     read contents of mybss
   c:   6019        str r1, [r3, #0] 
     write to address of myextern
   e:   4b09        ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (34 <notmain+0x34>)
     read address to mydata
  10:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
     read contents of mydata from address of mydata
  12:   3301        adds    r3, #1
     add one to contents of mydata
   14:  6013        str r3, [r2, #0]
     store in mybss
  16:   00ad        lsls    r5, r5, #2
     multiply 250*4 = 1000 ra counts to 1000

  this is the for(ra loop top
  18:   0020        movs    r0, r4
     put ra in the register that is passed to fun as a parameter
  1a:   3401        adds    r4, #1
     ra = ra + 1
  1c:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <fun>
     call fun, this is an object the real address is filled in by the linker
  20:   42ac        cmp r4, r5
     is ra == 1000?
  22:   d1f9        bne.n   18 <notmain+0x18>
     if ra!=1000 then go around the loop again

  24:   4804        ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; (38 <notmain+0x38>)
     they cheated here, I did/do not change mystatic so it is essentially a constant so they load the constant not the address...

I should "fix" that.
26:   bc70        pop {r4, r5, r6}
28:   bc02        pop {r1}
2a:   4708        bx  r1
...
    2c   mybss address
    30   myextern address
    34   mydata address

  38:   33333300    teqcc   r3, #0, 6

textbooks and conversation will say that local variables are "on the stack".
The way this code is generated for the code I wrote what happens instead is
   0:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
  26:   bc70        pop {r4, r5, r6}

We needed two registers worth of information the loop variable ra and the value 1000 that the loop variable counts to.  r0-r3 are volatile registers per the calling convention.  The function can mess with them and does not have to save them.   If we have a callee that needs r4/r5 they will save them, we are saving the r4/r5 local variables from some caller above us. So they are "on the stack" just not within this function.
To your question.  The compiler has generated code that honors the types of memory spaces and separated them.  It has generated the code so that the linker can then supply all the addresses for these sections.  So long as the linker script puts them in the proper place.  The compiler does not know the address space.  At the same time the compiler has generated no runtime comparisons nor protections in the code itself.
Other than the call to fun the compiler has generated code that can reach anywhere in the address space making the linkers job easier.
The instruction set plus compiler heavily determines the compiler/linker relationship.  They are an intimate couple, have to be careful if you try to mix and match.  These objects are in elf format too and the info the linker needs to fill in these gaps and finish these binaries.
unsigned int mydata = 0x22222200; //read/write, initialized, .data
unsigned int mybss;  //read/write, uninitialized, .bss
int notmain ( void )
{
    mybss=mydata;
    return 0;
}

And a bootstrap
flash.s
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.word 0x20010000
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b done
.thumb_func
done:   b .

Your linker script had a typo
MEMORY 
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
}

build it
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding  -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.o > notmain.c.list
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings  flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o -o notmain.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary notmain.elf notmain.bin



Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <reset-0x8>:
 8000000:   20010000    andcs   r0, r1, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <notmain>
 800000c:   e7ff        b.n 800000e <done>

0800000e <done>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <done>

08000010 <notmain>:
 8000010:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (800001c <notmain+0xc>)
 8000012:   681a        ldr r2, [r3, #0]
 8000014:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (8000020 <notmain+0x10>)
 8000016:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000018:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
 800001a:   4770        bx  lr
 800001c:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0
 8000020:   20000004    andcs   r0, r0, r4

Disassembly of section .data:

20000000 <mydata>:
20000000:   22222200    eorcs   r2, r2, #0, 4

Disassembly of section .bss:

20000004 <mybss>:
20000004:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0



Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <reset-0x8>:
 8000000:   20010000    andcs   r0, r1, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <notmain>
 800000c:   e7ff        b.n 800000e <done>

0800000e <done>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <done>

08000010 <notmain>:
 8000010:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (800001c <notmain+0xc>)
 8000012:   681a        ldr r2, [r3, #0]
 8000014:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (8000020 <notmain+0x10>)
 8000016:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000018:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
 800001a:   4770        bx  lr
 800001c:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0
 8000020:   20000004    andcs   r0, r0, r4

Disassembly of section .data:

20000000 <mydata>:
20000000:   22222200    eorcs   r2, r2, #0, 4

Disassembly of section .bss:

20000004 <mybss>:
20000004:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

this is not good
00000000  00 00 01 20 09 00 00 08  00 f0 02 f8 ff e7 fe e7  |... ............|
00000010  02 4b 1a 68 02 4b 00 20  1a 60 70 47 00 00 00 20  |.K.h.K. .`pG... |
00000020  04 00 00 20 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |... ............|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
18000000  00 22 22 22                                       |."""|
18000004

very bad
ls -al notmain.bin
-rwxrwxr-x 1 hello hello 402653188 Aug 10 01:19 notmain.bin

some folks will fill up their hard drive prematurely calling objcopy, try this and see for yourself
MEMORY 
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0xF0000000, LENGTH = 16K
}

Anyway, the problem is that the flash image will not contain the .data values so the 0x22222200 does not get read and written to bss.  The C code output does not functionally implement our C code.  Not the compiler's fault, not the linker's fault. The human's fault.
MEMORY 
{
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > FLASH
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > FLASH
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > RAM AT > FLASH
    .data   : { *(.data*)   } > RAM AT > FLASH
}

same
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <reset-0x8>:
 8000000:   20010000    andcs   r0, r1, r0
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <notmain>
 800000c:   e7ff        b.n 800000e <done>

0800000e <done>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <done>

08000010 <notmain>:
 8000010:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (800001c <notmain+0xc>)
 8000012:   681a        ldr r2, [r3, #0]
 8000014:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (8000020 <notmain+0x10>)
 8000016:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 8000018:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
 800001a:   4770        bx  lr
 800001c:   20000004    andcs   r0, r0, r4
 8000020:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .bss:

20000000 <mybss>:
20000000:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .data:

20000004 <mydata>:
20000004:   22222200    eorcs   r2, r2, #0, 4

but
hexdump -C notmain.bin 
00000000  00 00 01 20 09 00 00 08  00 f0 02 f8 ff e7 fe e7  |... ............|
00000010  02 4b 1a 68 02 4b 00 20  1a 60 70 47 04 00 00 20  |.K.h.K. .`pG... |
00000020  00 00 00 20 00 22 22 22                           |... ."""|
00000028

The > RAM AT > FLASH means link the code so that this section is in the RAM address space, but also make a copy of it (if loadable) in the FLASH memory space.  The elf file now no longer says that the .data nor .bss are part of the output -O binary file format.  The flash image we need to load into the part.
Now we have to figure out where .data is and how big .bss is.
I intentionally do not use (rwx) and (rx) because you are basically in the MEMORY area saying I want  you do to this to sections, and then in SECTIONS you are saying I want you to do this with sections, when there is a conflict guess what, the linker decides the winner and it is not you, without telling you.  golly gee I have to add .rodata to SECTIONS, small price.
MEMORY 
{
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > FLASH
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > FLASH
    __a__ = .;
    .bss    : 
    { 
    __b__ = .;
    *(.bss*)    
    __c__ = .;
    } > RAM AT > FLASH
    __d__ = .;
    .data   : 
    { 
    __e__ = .;
    *(.data*)   
    __f__ = .;
    } > RAM AT > FLASH
    __g__ = .;
}

added
.align
hello:
.word __a__
.word __b__
.word __c__
.word __d__

Giving
08000010 <hello>:
 8000010:   08000034 __a__
 8000014:   20000000 __b__
 8000018:   20000000 __c__
 800001c:   20000004 __d__

and Im hosed...
00000000  00 00 01 20 09 00 00 08  00 f0 0a f8 ff e7 fe e7  |... ............|
00000010  34 00 00 08 00 00 00 20  00 00 00 20 04 00 00 20  |4...... ... ... |
00000020  02 4b 1a 68 02 4b 00 20  1a 60 70 47 04 00 00 20  |.K.h.K. .`pG... |
00000030  00 00 00 20 00 22 22 22                           |... ."""|
00000038

The flash/rom address to .data is 0x08000034 not 0x20000004 so...
Oh, first.
arm-none-eabi-nm notmain.elf 
08000034 T __a__
20000000 B __b__
20000000 B __c__
20000004 B __d__
0800000e t done
20000004 D __e__
20000008 D __f__
20000008 D __g__
08000010 t hello
20000000 B mybss
20000004 D mydata
08000020 T notmain
08000008 t reset

Did not have to .word them into the binary but that is one way to see it...
The linker is creating "addresses" with variable names, folks tend to do the double underscore that is not required in any way...any variable that is not reserved and does not have a conflict with any other variable in the program.
flash.ld
MEMORY 
{
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 16K
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > FLASH
   .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > FLASH

   __data_rom_start__ = .;
   .data : {
    __data_start__ = .;
    *(.data*)
   } > RAM AT > FLASH
   __data_end__ = .;
   __data_size__ = __data_end__ - __data_start__;

   .bss  : {
   __bss_start__ = .;
   *(.bss*)
   } > RAM AT > FLASH
   __bss_end__ = .;
   __bss_size__ = __bss_end__ - __bss_start__;

}

flash.s
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.word 0x20010000
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:

    ldr r0,=0
    ldr r1,=__bss_start__
    ldr r2,=__bss_end__
bss_zero:
    str r0,[r1]
    add r1,#4
    cmp r1,r2
    bne bss_zero

    ldr r1,=__data_rom_start__
    ldr r2,=__data_start__
    ldr r3,=__data_end__
data_copy:
    ldr r0,[r1]
    str r0,[r2]
    add r1,#4
    add r2,#4
    cmp r2,r3
    bne data_copy

    bl notmain

    b done
.thumb_func
done:   b .


Disassembly of section .data:

20000000 <mydata>:
20000000:   22222200    eorcs   r2, r2, #0, 4

Disassembly of section .bss:

20000004 <mybss>:
20000004:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0


20000008 B __bss_end__
00000004 A __bss_size__
20000004 B __bss_start__
20000004 D __data_end__
0800005c T __data_rom_start__
00000004 A __data_size__
20000000 D __data_start__


00000000  00 00 01 20 09 00 00 08  09 48 0a 49 0a 4a 08 60  |... .....H.I.J.`|
00000010  04 31 91 42 fb d1 09 49  09 4a 0a 4b 08 68 10 60  |.1.B...I.J.K.h.`|
00000020  04 31 04 32 9a 42 f9 d1  00 f0 0e f8 ff e7 fe e7  |.1.2.B..........|
00000030  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 20  08 00 00 20 5c 00 00 08  |....... ... \...|
00000040  00 00 00 20 04 00 00 20  02 4b 1a 68 02 4b 00 20  |... ... .K.h.K. |
00000050  1a 60 70 47 00 00 00 20  04 00 00 20 00 22 22 22  |.`pG... ... ."""|
00000060

I think that got it.  Hopefully this quickly coded and not remotely tested code is correct.
You can see the intimate relationship between linker script and bootstrap.  Now the C generated code will actually do what we asked.  At a system level we, with the tools as tools (a hammer does not perfectly drive a nail by itself without smashed fingers or holes in the wall, it is a tool in a system).  The compiler (and assembler) generate and separate the executable read only, read only data and read/write data (zero init or not) into separate sections.  The compiler generates code that ideally does not cross any of these boundaries.  The linker script, per our instructions, places those different sections where we tell it to in the order we say (well gnu linker sometimes ignores what you say, gotta examine the file).
Note how much was done without actually running (and crashing) on hardware.
The tools do what you tell them.
flash.ld
MEMORY 
{
  FLASH : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 64K
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > FLASH
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > FLASH
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > FLASH
}

flash.s
notmain.c
int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int *mylocal;
    mylocal=(unsigned int *)notmain;
    mylocal[0]=10;
    return 0;
}

result
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <reset-0x8>:
 8000000:   08000800    stmdaeq r0, {fp}
 8000004:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset>:
 8000008:   f000 f802   bl  8000010 <notmain>
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <reset+0x4>
    ...

08000010 <notmain>:
 8000010:   220a        movs    r2, #10
 8000012:   4b04        ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; (8000024 <notmain+0x14>)
 8000014:   701a        strb    r2, [r3, #0]
 8000016:   2200        movs    r2, #0
 8000018:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 800001a:   705a        strb    r2, [r3, #1]
 800001c:   709a        strb    r2, [r3, #2]
 800001e:   70da        strb    r2, [r3, #3]
 8000020:   4770        bx  lr
 8000022:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
 8000024:   08000011    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r4}

It was very happy to generate a binary that is all in flash (I did not make .data nor .bss but you can see it will just do it).
It was happy to have my stack pointer init to a flash address.  I did not cause it to actually use the stack but if you make it call an external function it will.
It was quite happy to take an address in flash space and write to it.  Now, interestingly, it did not generate code that would cause an alignment fault.
If I change it from notmain to reset and make reset global.  With some cheating I guess..
extern unsigned int reset;

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int *mylocal;
    mylocal=(unsigned int *)reset;
    mylocal[0]=10;
    return 0;
}

08000010 :
8000010:   220a        movs    r2, #10
8000012:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (800001c <notmain+0xc>)
8000014:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
8000016:   2000        movs    r0, #0
8000018:   601a        str r2, [r3, #0]
800001a:   4770        bx  lr
800001c:   08000009    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}
On top of everything else we can get an alignment fault.
Not the compiler's fault.  Not the linker's fault.  The programmer's fault.
Has nothing to do with bare metal the tools do not know bare metal from an operating system app.   The gcc you make Linux or Windows binaries from, has a linker script and bootstrap buried in it that are married with each other and the operating system and the tools do what they are told.
So this will not actually write to the flash.  The logic prevents that, there is generally a procedure (varies by flash and chip) required in order to write to the flash and that does not necessarily include an actual store to the address you want something stored, depends on the procedure.  There is a non st chip vendor part that did let me simply write to flash by just writing to those addresses and it changed the flash.  Super scary it was more of case of a procedure to NOT let that happen.
The tools do what you tell them.  If you want the fetches, loads and stores to land in proper addresses and not trash flash, peripherals or memory.  That is a system engineering problem not a tools problem.  When you get good code plus good tools and combine them properly for the target, then there will not be any going out of bounds (well, exceptions like stack overflows can cause pretty much any kind of failure, that is also part of your system design though).
Why notmain vs main.  Most toolchains, including gnu, can or will add extra to the binary when it sees it is a C program because of main().  So it is a simple, old, trick to prevent that.  Some name other than main() or other entry points (WinMain()?)) for other targets or languages.
Targets other than arm, risc-v for example can/will generate .sdata, .sbss as well as .data and .bss and other sections specific to what the authors of that target implementation wanted.  And you have to deal with that, I still argue not to use (rwx) and (rx) but you will see lots of folks doing it.
The gnu linker script language is extremely painful, the documentation is of little help, you will not be successful without doing things as above, hacking your way through it and hoping for the best.  99.99..% with a lot of 9s folks never mess with it they use the script that comes with the gnu toolchain they installed not knowing there is one in there.  A huge, complicated, married not only to the bootstrap but the C library as well as the C library is likely the owner of the bootstrap and linker script.  All tuned to the target and operating system target.  Some parts of that script indicating they may not have necessarily fully understood the linker script and hacked their way from some prior linker script...The extremely rare case of doing it yourself AND wanting .data and a zeroed .bss without help, is likely guaranteed to fail (help = borrowing from others including looking at others scripts)(docs != help).  Since bare metal implies no C library calls since that adds much more pain than what you are implying, It is trivial to do without .data and not care if .bss is zeroed making the linker script
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
}

and the bootstrap
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.word 0x20001000
.word reset

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b .

Your experience may be different. If you are on a Raspberry Pi Pico for example or other ram only solution, then there are some tools tricks you can do to get zeroed .bss and .data without a complicated linker script:
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > ram
    .data   : { *(.data*)   } > ram
}

And one more trick to make that work.  With the same just branch to main bootstrap.
I do not know where your question was really headed, and this was an overkill tangent to the answers in comments saying the linker script nor compiler protect writes to the flash, but if you were truly going to head down either the roll your own linker script and or try to understand the rest of the linker script from some sandbox that you are looking at.  Hacking is required, almost nobody really knows how it works (almost everything I know is above and it is a tiny bit of the linker script language) and you have to experiment (hack) your way through which also includes learning some of the other binutils tools and their nuances.
The compiler tags the pickup trucks with yellow stickers and hatch backs with blue (if you do not muck with its settings).  You have to tell the linker script to sort them into different parking lots.  Neither tool prevents them from driving through a fence and invading the other parking lot or crashing into other vehicles.

Thank you for your patient response. I think the example you gave about the car was excellent. I've rephrased my question in the comments; could you please take another look
